# Are there any behavioural differences before and after this javascript refactoring?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, refactoring, yui

I recently had to refactor a chunk of javascript that is using YUI.

So, originally it was something like this:

```
YAHOO.namespace('space.time');
YAHOO.space.time = (function() {
    var b = document.getelementbyid("aifdsgyalierg");

    function c(b) {
        var a = new YAHOO.util.Anim(d, b); //just assume the parameters are correct here
        a.method = YAHOO.util.Easing.easeOut;        
        a.animate();
    };

    return { c:c };
})();
```

For the sake of being able to inject dependencies, i refactored it to the below:

```
YAHOO.namespace('space.time');
YAHOO.namespace('space.timefn');
YAHOO.space.timefn = function(yuianim) {
    var b = document.getelementbyid("aifdsgyalierg");

    function c(d) {
        var a = new yuianim(d, b); //just assume the parameters are correct here
        a.method = YAHOO.util.Easing.easeOut;        
        a.animate();
    };

    return { c:c };
};
YAHOO.space.time = YAHOO.space.timefn(YAHOO.util.Anim);
```

So..

1) Ignoring any committed fallacies.. Will the behaviour of the two snippets differ?

2) What fallacies have i committed?